# Failure to deploy code with External Credential

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, metadata-api

Were you able to deploy External Credential, or have you left it out as a manual step?

We currently try to deploy a package with a Named Credential, using External Credential (new on Winter'23) with API version 56.0 using SFDX, and we keep getting GACKs. This pipeline's first step is running deployment validation (`--checkonly`).

The current GACK is `An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 819874669-15988 (2056426840)`.

I have also checked the [Metadata Coverage Report for v56](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/56) and the Salesforce CLI Release Notes (it since [7.173.0 - October](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/blob/main/releasenotes/sfdx/README.md#71730-oct-20-2022)).

Comment: Based on Salesforce backend logs, the stacktrace `2056426840` points to `java.lang.ClassCastException: class system.user.permission.CustomPermissionSetObject cannot be cast to class system.user.permission.PermissionSetObject` I can see this was also reported on [Github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1781) and tagged to internal bug # W-12075756

Comment: Wow @Swetha, thanks a lot for such a quick update. Because I also don't have access to GUS is there a Know Issue or timeline to expect it to be fixed?

Comment: I am following up internally and will let you know as I have more details. Thanks

Comment: Hello @Swetha: thanks for following up internally, were you able to get more insights that you could share?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I've been waiting for a meaningful update to post. The team has filed W-12361127 and the fix will be rolled out in 242 patch(Safe Harbour) Thank you.

Comment: Hey Swetha, no worries, it is fair enough. Would 242 mean Spring'23 release?

Comment: That is correct. 242 is Spring'23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the stacktrace ID (2056426840) corresponds to `java.lang.ClassCastException: class system.user.permission.CustomPermissionSetObject cannot be cast to class system.user.permission.PermissionSetObject` based on the Salesforce backend logs and this was also reported on [Github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1781) by another user.

Upon following up with the concerned Salesforce product development team, the issue has been fixed as part of #W-12361127 and the fix has been rolled out last week in the Spring'23 release patch(242)